# How can I use grep and set to replace buggy python in multiple files

Tags: unix, python-3.x, sed, grep

I have I collection of python files which use the following try except formatting

```
try:
    # some code....
except Exception, e:
    # some exception code....
```

This is an easy fix, and should look like

```
try:
    # some code....
except SomeException as e:
    # some exception code....
```

I have tried using the command to change the text in all of these files

```
grep -Erl "(*.)(, e:)" | xargs sed -i's/\(*.\)\(, e:\)/\1 as e:/'
```

But it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/except/{ s/\(except\) \([^,]\+\)\(, e:\)/\1 \2 as e:/}' your_python.py
```

This will take the backup of the original file with `.bak` extension.

Answer (score 0):

To match zero or more characters with a regex, use `.*`, not `*.`.  Also, you need a space between `-i` and the command to `sed`.

Comment: That made the command run without errors, but it did not replace the text in the files